# Visualize Convolutional filters keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

How to get trained filters' values out of a CNN and then plot them?
model.layers[0].get_weights() doesn't return filters' values so I can't plot them

code: https://gitlab.com/F171pp0/CNN_filters/blob/master/CNN%20notebook.ipynb

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Hey Fillippo, This awesome Keras blog post is a very good start for visualizing filters with Keras:
http://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html
It has the code to visualize the convolutional filter

Comment: updated with the code